# error iterating through rows in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df0:             A           B          C
Date
2017-04-13  884.669983  139.389999  46.900002
2017-04-17  901.989990  141.419998  47.389999
2017-04-18  903.780029  140.960007  47.560001
2017-04-19  899.200012  142.270004  47.000000
2017-04-20  902.059998  143.800003  47.669998
2017-04-21  898.530029  143.679993  47.520000
```

I am simply looking forward to create a new dataframe `main_df` that what does is substract the row in `i+1` from the row `i` and turn that resulting row to absolute numbers and introduce it into a new dataframe:

Here is what I have tried:

```
main_df=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df0)):
    main_df.iloc[i]=np.absolute(df0.iloc[i+1]-df0.iloc[i])
print(main_df)
```

outputs the error `single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`

Which is quite confusing given that iterating with the `iloc` property has worked correctly in other ocasiones.

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem in last loop - you try select row with is not in df (`iloc[i+1]`), so get `error`.

Solution:

[`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) + [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) + [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html):

```
df = df.sub(df.shift(-1)).abs()
print (df)
                    A         B         C
Date                                     
2017-04-13  17.320007  2.029999  0.489997
2017-04-17   1.790039  0.459991  0.170002
2017-04-18   4.580017  1.309997  0.560001
2017-04-19   2.859986  1.529999  0.669998
2017-04-20   3.529969  0.120010  0.149998
2017-04-21        NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Also if need remove last `NaN` row use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select all rows without last:

```
df = df.sub(df.shift(-1)).abs().iloc[:-1]
print (df)
                    A         B         C
Date                                     
2017-04-13  17.320007  2.029999  0.489997
2017-04-17   1.790039  0.459991  0.170002
2017-04-18   4.580017  1.309997  0.560001
2017-04-19   2.859986  1.529999  0.669998
2017-04-20   3.529969  0.120010  0.149998
```

Answer (score 3):

**`pandas`**
Use [**`diff`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

```
main_df = df0.diff(-1).abs()

                    A         B         C
Date                                     
2017-04-13  17.320007  2.029999  0.489997
2017-04-17   1.790039  0.459991  0.170002
2017-04-18   4.580017  1.309997  0.560001
2017-04-19   2.859986  1.529999  0.669998
2017-04-20   3.529969  0.120010  0.149998
2017-04-21        NaN       NaN       NaN
```

**`numpy`**

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.abs(np.diff(df0.values, axis=0)),
    df0.index[:-1], df0.columns
)

                    A         B         C
Date                                     
2017-04-13  17.320007  2.029999  0.489997
2017-04-17   1.790039  0.459991  0.170002
2017-04-18   4.580017  1.309997  0.560001
2017-04-19   2.859986  1.529999  0.669998
2017-04-20   3.529969  0.120010  0.149998
```

---

**OP's iteration**
Notice I did three things to fix your code:

1. I added `columns` to your initial dataframe
2. I `range` from `0` to `len(df0) - 1`
3. I looked up the index value for position `i` so I could use `loc` to assign new rows

---

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df0.columns)
for i in range(len(df0) - 1):
    idx = df0.index[i]
    main_df.loc[idx] = np.absolute(df0.iloc[i+1]-df0.iloc[i])

                    A         B         C
Date                                     
2017-04-13  17.320007  2.029999  0.489997
2017-04-17   1.790039  0.459991  0.170002
2017-04-18   4.580017  1.309997  0.560001
2017-04-19   2.859986  1.529999  0.669998
2017-04-20   3.529969  0.120010  0.149998
```